# Is there a way to get Indy to accept expired cookies?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, indy

Using Delphi XE2 Update 4 and Indy components 10.5.8.0 as installed by Delphi.

A website I am trying to work with is deliberately sending me a cookie with an already expired date for security reasons.  It is deliberate on their part and I have to live with it and other developers working with them have managed to do so.

The server response to my `IdHTTP.Get()` looks like this:

```
Recv 8/30/2012 3:06:15 PM: HTTP/1.1 200 OK<EOL>
Date: Thu, 30 Aug 2012 19:06:35 GMT<EOL>
Server: Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS)<EOL>
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.1.6<EOL>
Set-Cookie: dati=eJxLtDKxqi62MrdSykyJLy1OLVKyLrYytVIyNjcxtISyc%2FLTM%2FNAbKAqt4CgYJfUMhDPEqinOB4omZ6aAuIbWilFgmkDkGGpeSWZaZkQ8wyNrZTSchKLMwryM%2FNK4ouKlaxrAYdvJUQ%3D; 
expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:03:00 GMT<EOL>
Content-Length: 16<EOL>
Connection: close<EOL>
Content-Type: text/plain;; charset=ISO-8859-1<EOL><EOL>
0 24.141.251.145
```

Note the 1970 expiry!  I have been using Indy for all of 3 days now and as near as I can tell this attempt to create a cookie is simply ignored by IdHttp and the associated CookieManager.

Assuming I need to receive and use the cookie anyway what would be the proper approach to capture it, or should I just run away screaming now?  I have a lot of Delphi experience but this is my first foray into the wonderful world of internet connectivity and this expired-on-arrival cookie business is leaving me scratching my head!

Comment: Can you modify the cookies EXPIRES date before you attempt to add it?

Answer (score 5):

Sending an expired cookie is how a webserver deletes a cookie on the client end.  Indy's cookie manager supports that.  When it receives a cookie, it will delete any existing cookie of the same name/domain/path trio and will then discard the new cookie if it is already expired.  This is hard-coded behavior.

If, for whatever reason, you have to keep the expired cookie (which does not make sense as no webclient should ever do that), you will have to use the `TIdCookieManager.OnNewCookie` event to alter the expiration of the cookie after it is parsed by `TIdCookie` but before it is processed by `TIdCookieManager`.  You can set the `TIdCookie.Expires` property to a future date, or to `0.0` to disable its expiration.  You will have to do this anyway, as `TIdCookieManager` implements cleanup of expired cookies (which is triggered whenever `TIdHTTP` asks for cookies to send in an HTTP request), so if you don't alter the expiration then the cookie will just get discarded anyway at a later time.

Comment: Thanks for the very speed reply!  I tried to intercept the cookie in the IdCookieManager1.OnNewCookie event but that event is not being fired when the cookie arrives.  the IdHTTP1 component points to the IdCookieManager1 but somehow the latter is not being used?  An internal cookie manager is being used instead perhaps?

Comment: If the event is not firing then either the `TIdHTTP.AllowCookies` property is false, the cookie is not being parsed correctly, or the cookie is being rejected as invalid (other than being expired). I'll look into it in a little bit.

Comment: I can confirm that AllowCookies has been set to true all along.  Since I am so new to Indy it is possible I am missing something else that is obvious but I have put a lot of hours into this now and I'm pretty sure I've covered at least the basics.  Does it matter that I am using the version distributed with Delphi XE2 update 4?  Should I download the development build and try that instead?  I *really* appreciate your help btw.  Thanks

Comment: It should be working fine with the XE2 version of Indy. Can you provide the actual URL that is sending the cookie so I can look at it directly?

Comment: I'm reluctant to post that link in a public place but if you are willing I can zip up my minimal project that illustrates the problem and send that to you instead.  The zip is 85k.  Where should I send it?  Again, thank you very much for this wonderful help.

Comment: I don't need the whole program, just the URL so I can run it and the cookie through TIdCookieManager. I have my own Indy test code. My email address is in my StackOverflow profile.

Comment: Using the current Indy 10 release, calling `TIdHTTP.Get()` with the URL you sent to me privately, the `TIdCookieManager.OnNewCookie` event fires as expected and `TIdCookieManager` accepts the cookie after updating the `TIdCookie.Expires` property. So it has to be an issue with something in your project, not with Indy itself. Are you ABSOLUTELY SURE that your `TIdCookieManager` component is assigned to the `TIdHTTP.CookieManager` property and the `TIdHTTP.AllowCookies` property is true?